# Lie algebra of Lie Group

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given the Lie group that consist from matrices like: \begin{bmatrix}1&x&z+1/2xy\\0&1&y\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

Find algebra Lie.

Using the next formula $\mathfrak{g}=T_I G=\left\{A^{\prime}\left(t_0\right) \in \operatorname{Mat}(n, \mathbb{R}) \mid A \in C^{\infty}((\alpha, \beta), G): A\left(t_0\right)=I\right\}$

Is next answer correct?

\begin{bmatrix}0&a&c+1/2ab\\0&0&b\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} where a,b,c from R.

Comment: first one z+(1/2) *(xy)

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of $G$ is a little strange -- if
$$ 
G = \{A \in \text{Mat}(3,\mathbb R): A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & x & z+\frac{1}{2}xy \\ 0 & 1 & y \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right), \quad x,y,z \in \mathbb R\},
$$
Then if $a=x, b=y,c= z+\frac{1}{2}xy$, then $a,b,c$ are arbitrary real numbers since $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y,z+\frac{1}{2}xy)$ has inverse $(a,b,c) \mapsto (a,b,c-\frac{1}{2}ab)$. But then $G=I_3+N$ where
$$
N = \{A\in \text{Mat}(3,\mathbb R): A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right), \quad a,b,c \in \mathbb R\},
$$
That is, if $E_{ij}$ denotes the elementary matrix with all entries $0$ except the one in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column, which is equal to $1$, then $N$ is $\text{span}\{E_{12},E_{13},E_{23}\}$.

In this case we have $\mathfrak{g} = \text{Lie}(G)=N$. Can you see how to show this using the definition you quote?

Comment: Yes, i see now. So, can i choose basis in g like in this case:

\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)

\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)

\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)

Comment: The group you mention is [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group)